# Show that $E_t$ is open - Am I right?

Tags: general-topology

Let $M$ be a topological space and $E\subset\mathbb{R}\times M$ be open.
Now fix $t\in\mathbb{R}$ and consider
$$
E_t:=\left\{x\in M: (t,x)\in E\right\}.
$$
Now I would like to show that $E_t\subset M$ is open.

Proof.

$E$ is within the product topology on $\mathbb{R}\times M$

If $x\in E_t$, then $(t,x)\in E$. Because then for the projection $(t,x)\mapsto x$ it has to be that $x$ is within a set of the topology on $M$, it follows that $E_t$ has to be in the topology on $M$.

Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find you argument a bit confused. Be explicit. So let $x \in E_t$. This means that $(t,x) \in E$. As $E$ is open in the product topology, we have $U \subset \mathbb{R}$ open and $V \subset M$ open such that $(t,x) \in U \times V \subset E$. If $x' \in V$ then $(t,x') \in U \times V \subset E$, so $x' \in E_t$. This means that $x \in V \subset E_t$, and thus $x$ is an interior point of $E_t$. As $x$ is arbitrary, $E_t$ is open.

Comment: I think I nearly got it. But why are $U\subset\mathbb{R}$ and $V\subset M$ open?

Comment: The definition of the product topology says that sets like $U \times V$ are a base for the topology; the statement follows directly from that.

Comment: $E$ is open. That means it is neighbourhood of each of its point, f.e. for $(t,x)\in E$. I.e. there is an open set $O$ (i.e. $O$ is in the product topology on $\mathbb{R}\times M$) such that $(t,x)\in O\subset E$. But why is $O$ of the form $U\times V$ where $U$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$ and $V$ is open in $M$? Because any open set can be written as a union of $p_1^{-1}(O_1)\cap p_2^{-1}(O_2)$, where $O_1$ open in $\mathbb{R}$, $O_2$ open in $M$. This what you meant?

Comment: $E$ is already open in the product topology. And a base is of the form $(p_1)^{-1}(O_1) \times (p_2)^{-1}(O_2) = O_1 \times O_2$.

Comment: I think I got it now. $E$ is open in the product topology on $\mathbb{R}\times M$, i.e. it can be written as some union $E=\bigcup\bigcap_{k=1}^{2}p_k^{-1}(O_k)$. Now $(t,x)\in E$, i.e. there are open sets $O_1$ in $\mathbb{R}$ and $O_2$ in $M$, such that $(t,x)\in p_1^{-1}(O_1)\cap p_2^{-1}(O_2)=O_1\times O_2$. And your $U$ and $V$ are these both sets that I called $O_1$ and $O_2$. Right?

Comment: I.E. I used another basis like you but I hope its okay what I wrote.

Comment: Yes, indeed. This is the argument in full.